# How to fix "The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized. Please import the module and try again"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm writing my first PowerShell script to load data from a CSV and then restart the following VMs using the PowerShell script.

Please find the Excel sheet sample data

[image]

Here is the Powershell script

```
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$SubscriptionId
)



$relativePath = Get-Item Data.xlsx | Resolve-Path -Relative
$inputs = Import-Excel $relativePath


#Connecting to particular Az Subscription
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

#Restart VM function
function RestartVM{
            [CmdletBinding()]
            param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$VMName,
                [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$ResourceGroupName
            )

Restart-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName

}


# for($i=0; $i -lt $inputs.Count; $i=$i+1)
# {
#     Write-Host "Process has been started for VM:" + $inputs[$i].VMName + "in the following resource group: " +  $inputs[$i].ResourceGroup
#     RestartVM -VMName $inputs[$i].VMName -ResourceGroupName $inputs[$i].ResourceGroup
# }


Workflow TestParallel{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$inputs
    )
   Write-Output $inputs
   Write-Output $inputs.Count
   Foreach -parallel($i in 0..1 ){
         Write-Output "Process has been started for VM:"  $inputs[$i].VMName " in the following resource group: "   $inputs[$i].ResourceGroup
         RestartVM -VMName $inputs[$i].VMName -ResourceGroupName $inputs[$i].ResourceGroup
   }
}

TestParallel -inputs $inputs
```

When I am executing the script in parallel for restarting the VM, I am getting the following error

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module and try again.
At TestParallel:42 char:42
```

Note: I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the commands in Parallel foreach (i.e to restart the VM)

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems as though the custom function `RestartVM` is redundant here. You can just call the official cmdlet `Restart-AzVM` inside your workflow rather than duplicate the same functionality. Given that the error is reporting the session hasn't been initialised properly, try `Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId` inside your workflow also.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you need to take a step back and evaluate what you're trying to achieve and then solve each step individually before trying to get the entire script working.

#### CSV or xlsx

You advise that you're trying to pull data from a CSV file but then you're using the `Import-Excel` module to load an xlsx.

If you are actually pulling from a CSV file then you can use `Import-CSV` without the need for `Import-Excel` at all.

#### Do you need to use workflow?

Given that you're attempting to use `Foreach -Parallel` I would draw the conclusion that you're attempting to use the newer PowerShell 7 features and therefore you can't use workflows anyway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2#powershell-workflow

If you are attempting to create your script inside an Azure Automation runbook then there is a recommendation that you should only use a workflow if you need to make use of checkpoints:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow

#### Parallel Execution - PowerShell 7

If you are planning on using parallelism to execute the restart and you are wanting to use the newer language features as part of PowerShell 7 then you can look at this article which explains using `Foreach-Object -Parallel`

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/

Comment: Agree on @BrettMillers answer. As an addon - if all you are looking to do is restart all the VMs in "paralell" (without waiting for execution each and every one) - you could consider doing Restart-AZVM -AsJob for the whole list of VMs and it will just return you the jobs that will be running async for you, restarting the VMs.